# How to change class attribute by reference?

Tags: python, class

```
class Stock:
  def __init__(self,
               stock = 'GOOG',
               period = '1Y',
               interval = 86400,
               market = 'NASDAQ'):

    self.stock = stock
    self.period = period
    self.inteval = interval
    self.market = market

    data = get_price_data({'q': stock, 'p': period, 'i': interval, 'x': market})
    self.data = data

MU = Stock('MU')
```

I'd like to be able to update attributes, for example `MU.period = '14d'` and have the data be recalculated automatically.

I tried doing something like

```
   @period.setter
    def period(self, val):
        self._period = val
        self.data = data(self.stock, self.period, self.interval, self.market)
```

but it threw an error `'str' object has no attribute 'setter'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `@period.setter` can only be done if you've already declared `period` as a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

You're also going to need a getter—which you usually just declare with the initial `@property`.

Finally, you probably want to go behind the `period` property and store stuff directly in the raw `_period` attribute in your `__init__`, because otherwise you're going to end up setting `self.data` twice.

So:

```
class Stock:
  def __init__(self,
               stock = 'GOOG',
               period = '1Y',
               interval = 86400,
               market = 'NASDAQ'):

    self.stock = stock
    self._period = period
    self.inteval = interval
    self.market = market

    data = get_price_data({'q': stock, 'p': period, 'i': interval, 'x': market})
    self.data = data

  @property
  def period(self):
      return self._period

  @period.setter
  def period(self, val):
      self._period = val
      self.data = data(self.stock, self.period, self.interval, self.market)
```

You might also want to make `data` a read-only `@property` while you're at it, to make sure nobody accidentally breaks it, but that may not be worth it ("consenting adults" and all that).

Comment: works perfect, thank you thank you!
(yeah, I just started getting into classes, lots to learn)

Comment: @Raksha Another idea you might want to try, if you're doing this for learning experience: make `data` a property instead of `period`. (It doesn't need a setter, only a getter.) And then look at `functools.lru_cache` to make it not waste time recalculating the `get_price_data` function if nothing has changed since the last time.